# ¿Cómo modifico el tamaño de la barra de progreso en Bootstrap 5?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

Estoy aprendiendo Bootstrap y no entiendo cómo lograr que la barra de progreso me quede de la siguiente manera:

[image: barra de progreso correcta]

Solo puedo hacer que ocupe todo el largo de la tarjeta de la siguiente manera:

```
<div class="card mat-card"> 
    <div class="skills d-flex">
        <h2 class="skills-title me-auto" style="padding-bottom: 20px">Hard Skills & Soft Skills</h2>
        <a href="#" class="btn-right"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
    </div>
    <div class="skills-details">
        <div class="skills-first d-flex justify-content-center">
            <h5>Compromiso</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="skills-edit d-flex justify-content-end">
            <a href="#" class="btn-right"><i class="fa fa-pen pe-4"></i></a>
            <a href="#" class="btn-right"><i class="fa-solid fa-trash"></i></a> 
        </div>
        <div class="progress">
            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped bg-success" role="progressbar" style="width: 100%" aria-valuenow="100" aria-valuemin="100" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
        </div>     
    </div>    
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías hacer lo siguiente, básicamente primero por css le doy un width específico a la clase progress y luego quito un border que está en la clase mat-card. Luego encierro toda la barra en un div al que le aplico display flex, y donde se alinean los elementos, finalmente pongo 2 span con una "X" y una "M" donde pondrías los botones deseados.

**El código HTML completo quedaría así:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="card mat-card">
      <div class="skills d-flex">
        <h2 class="skills-title me-auto" style="padding-bottom: 20px">
          Hard Skills & Soft Skills
        </h2>
        <a href="#" class="btn-right"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
      </div>
      <div class="skills-details">
        <div class="skills-first d-flex justify-content-center">
          <h5>Compromiso</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="skills-edit d-flex justify-content-end">
          <a href="#" class="btn-right"><i class="fa fa-pen pe-4"></i></a>
          <a href="#" class="btn-right"><i class="fa-solid fa-trash"></i></a>
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-end">
          <div class="progress">
            <div
              class="progress-bar progress-bar-striped bg-success"
              role="progressbar"
              style="width: 100%"
              aria-valuenow="100"
              aria-valuemin="100"
              aria-valuemax="100"
            ></div>
          </div>
          <span class="ms-3">X</span>
          <span class="ms-3">M</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**El CSS qudaría así:**

```
.progress {
    width: 600px;
}

.mat-card {
border: none;
}
```

**El resultado final sería algo así:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

También podrías agregar algo así en el **CSS** para que la barra tenga un ancho máximo deseado y se ajuste a la pantalla si esta se hace más chica, además agregué un pequeño padding a los costados para que no se pegue a los bordes al achicarla.

**CSS Final:**

```
.progress {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 600px;
}

.mat-card {
  padding: 0 15px;
  border: none;
}
```